# Bootstrap 3.0 @navbarCollapseWidth

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

`navbar-collapse min-width: 767px`

I want navbar-collapse in `max-width: 991px`, in customize page I can't find `@navbarCollapseWidth`

This is bootstrap 3.0, my nav is too big for 767 and i want it to collapse earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. download the latest version from https://github.com/bassjobsen/jamedo-bootstrap-start-theme/archive/master.zip
2. this zip contains the Less files open less/variables.less

This file contains the line:

```
// Point at which the navbar stops collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-tablet;
```

change this to:

```
// Point at which the navbar stops collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint:     992px;
```

1. Recompile your css files (`>>lessc less/bootstrap.less`) files or rebuild Bootstrap (`grunt dist`)

Answer (score 0):

There is still a problem with drowpdowns in collapsed mode for sizes between `@screen-tablet` and the size you put to `@grid-float-breakpoint` (992 in this case).

I think there is a bug that the dropdown media query is not using `@grid-float-breakpoint` and instead refers to `@screen-xs-max` instead in nabar.less file.

If you override this too you get correct dropdowns and collapse point.

Instead of

```
.navbar-nav {
    @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
        // Dropdowns get custom display when collapsed
    .open .dropdown-menu {
        position: static;
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;

        > li > a,
        .dropdown-header {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
        }

        > li > a {
            line-height: @line-height-computed;

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                background-image: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

use

```
.navbar-nav {
    @media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
        // Dropdowns get custom display when collapsed
        .open .dropdown-menu {
           position: static;
           float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
        box-shadow: none;

        > li > a,
        .dropdown-header {
            padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
        }

        > li > a {
            line-height: @line-height-computed;

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                background-image: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```